# Importing java class to jsp causing cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, jsp

JSP code:

```
    <%@ page import = "action.LoginCheckAction" %>
<%
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

    LoginCheckAction ls = new LoginCheckAction();
    ls.printSomething(username);
%>
```

Java class:

```
    package action;

public class LoginCheckAction{
    public LoginCheckAction(){
        super();
    }

    public void printSomething(String username){
        System.out.println(username);
    }
}
```

Another JSP file is sending post data to the JSP code posted here. 
I am trying to use the method available in my Java file that is located in another directory, inside the package action, however it keeps giving me a `LoginCheckAction cannot be resolved to a type`.

I tried importing `action.*` instead, and it did not work.

Can anyone please explain what the problem is?

Comment: the action.LoginCheckAction class is not in the class path at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think off is that LoginCheckAction source code is not being compilled properly or added to the war or EAR of your web application deployment.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by WAR or EAR. I read a bit about them, but I have nothing like that. My code is already in the Tomcat Webapps folder.

Comment: Check if under application WEB-INF folder you have this structure classes\action\LoginCheckAction.class

Comment: I don't. It's WEB-INF/.classpath

Comment: That is what I meant. The Java file LoginCheckAction is not being compiled (into a .class file) nor being placed int eh WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: Alright. I fixed the issue. It is now building into WEB-INF/classes/action. But it's still giving me the same error after restarting the server.

Comment: I never initially deployed it. Created it inside tomcat's webapps directly. Is that wrong?

Comment: You can redeploy application from Tomcat application manager (http://localhost:8080/manager)

Comment: Alright. Well I found what the problem was. For some reason, tomcat wasn't getting to WEB-INF since it was under a folder called WebContent. So I just removed WebContent and put WEB-INF straight under the project, on the same level of the src folder containing my Java files, and the jsp folder containing my jsp files. Thanks for the help Alvaro.

Answer (score 0):

Try without space `<%@ page import="action.LoginCheckAction" %>`

Comment: Same problem. For some reason it keeps thinking that action.LoginCheckAction is a package.

Comment: Once you trim the spaces like above save and reload the project, might do the  trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but it didn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

if you have build your project using maven, sometimes it's unable to compile classes and generate the war and jar file.Build the project to eclipse or netbeans project by :-
1. Go to the directory of the project
2. Hold `shift` and right click and click on `open command prompt here`
3. Type `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you want to build the project for eclipse IDE or `mvn netbeans:netbeans` if you want to build the project for netbeans
4. Close and open the project and your errors should be resolved

Answer (score 0):

if you have build your project using maven, sometimes it's unable to compile classes and generate the war and jar file.Build the project to eclipse or netbeans project by :-

1. Go to the directory of the project
2. Hold `shift` and right click and click on `open command prompt here`
3. Type `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you want to build the project for eclipse IDE or `mvn netbeans:netbeans` if you want to build the project for netbeans
4. Close and open the project and your errors should be resolved